# Ubuntu Software Center: The upload does not appear to be a valid click package

Tags: software-center, application-development, deb, error-handling

I'm trying to upload an application to the Ubuntu Software Center and have encountered this error when uploading the **.deb** file:

```
The upload does not appear to be a valid click package.
```

What is the reason for this error?

Comment: look at the top of the page, click on "Desktop". is that the section you are in?

Comment: No, "Developer"

Comment: look here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LKBys.png

Comment: Thnx it works :) Could you post as an answer so that I can give you credit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you were accidentally in the phone section, clicks are currently for Ubuntu Touch. Click on "Desktop" as shown here:

[image]

That should get you in the right section, also remember that you won't get e-mail's for notes on the submission, so check the status and feedback areas often.